# Selenium WebDriver: Extracting strings in a search result using a loop

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on all the search results with a loop and get the title strings from each of the results. So it would click on a result try to extract the string.

```
    String title = null; 
    List <WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.className("thumbnail"));
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());

    for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
        links = driver.findElements(By.className("thumbnail")); // this step is must, because whenever you go to other page all store WebElements in a list will wash out
        links.get(i).click();
   //it opens the search result in a new tab and gains focus on that tab
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        By addItem = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"HEADING\"]");

        // get the "Add Item" element
        WebElement element1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(addItem));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element1));

        if(!driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"HEADING\"]")).isEmpty()) {
            title = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"HEADING\"]")).getText();
        }
        else {
             System.out.println("Title is missing");
        }
        System.out.println(title);

        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0)); //Switching to first tab
    }
```

The code is extracting the title on the first page rather than the page it clicked on. I'm also trying to extract other strings such as address, email, etc but i'm just testing this out. How do I fix this? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few things that I changed.

1. I moved all your locators (and some other declarations) to the top and outside of the loop so they aren't redeclared inside the loop and so that they can be referenced by the `.findElement()` calls.
2. Since you are only using the current window handle, changed the variable type to `String` and just got the current window handle (instead of the collection of handles) so that you can switch back to the main tab at the end of the loop.
3. Moved the staleness check right after the click since that's where you need it and changed it to wait for the thumbnail that was just clicked.
4. Changed the XPath locator to use ID since that's all you were referencing. It's faster, shorter, and easier to read.
5. The second wait now waits for the collection of elements and then uses that collection to test for empty and get the text of the first in the collection.

   ```
   By addItemLocator = By.id("HEADING");
   By thumbnailsLocator = By.className("thumbnail");
   List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(thumbnailsLocator);
   String originalTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
   Set<String> tabs = driver.getWindowHandles();
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

   for(int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++)
   {
       links = driver.findElements(thumbnailsLocator); // this step is must, because whenever you go to other page all store WebElements in a list will wash out
       links.get(i).click();

       // it opens the search result in a new tab and gains focus on that tab

       // switch to the new window
       for(String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
           if (!handle.equals(originalTab))
           {
               driver.switchTo().window(handle);
               break;
           }
       }

       // get the "Add Item" element
       List<WebElement> addItems = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(addItemLocator));

       if(!addItems.isEmpty())
       {
           System.out.println(addItems.get(0).getText());
       }
       else
       {
           System.out.println("Title is missing");
       }

       driver.close(); // close current tab
       driver.switchTo().window(originalTab); // switch to original tab
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed answer but i'm getting the following error...Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element ([[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP  -> class name: thumbnail]) to become stale (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:82)
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:231)
 at finalEx.NewTest.main(NewTest.java:51)

Comment: The error line:          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(links.get(i)));

Comment: Does the click refresh the page or navigate to a new page? You might just comment that line out. I put it in there because you had it in yours, I just changed what element was being waited on. With a wait for staleness, you need to get a reference to an element *before* the click and then wait for it to be stale *after* the click.

Comment: The click navigates to a new page in a new tab. So..it clicks on the first result > opens a new tab of the first result > looks for the heading(title) and extracts it.

Comment: I found the bug, it doesn't focus on the new tab that's been opened. I tried driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));  but it's giving me java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Comment: Right... I was in the process of updating the answer after I realized that.